# Is there a difference between Dialog.getContext() and the Activity that made the dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-context

Our application uses nested dialogs, and we've been successfully making one dialog that sits on top of another dialog by constructing it from the first dialog's `getContext()` method.  So:

Activity:

```
//...
Dialog1 dialog = new Dialog1(this);
dialog.show();
//...
```

Dialog1:

```
//...
Dialog1(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //etc.
}

public void onSomeCondition() {
    Dialog2 dialog2 = new Dialog2(getContext());
    dialog2.show();
    //etc.
}
```

However, there is a circumstance where we want to launch Dialog2 directly from the Activity while Dialog1 is still visible.  So we put this method in the Activity:

```
public void onSomeOtherCondition() {
    Dialog2 dialog = new Dialog2(this); //crunch
    dialog.show();
    //etc.
}
```

The window manager doesn't like this at all.  So is it that `getContext()` is actually NOT exactly the same as the `ContextWrapper`-ness in the Activity?  If so exactly how does this secondary context differ from the primary one, and if (for example) you passed back `getContext()` from a dialog to a calling Activity, would that create the same leak risk as holding on to a Context reference elsewhere can do?

If it's not the context, what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain if the contexts are different (it would appear they are), but I suspect the problem is that you are not dismissing Dialog1 before attempting to start Dialog2 from your Activity. The WindowManager is probably angry because you are attempting to start a dialog on top of your Activity, but Dialog1 is already there.

Long story short, I think you need:

```
    public void onSomeOtherCondition() {
         this.dismiss();
         mActivity.onSomeOtherCondition(); //we have a reference to the activity
    }
```

**EDIT**

The solution I proposed in the comments is to pass Dialog1's context to mActivity.onSomeOtherCondition so that you can create Dialog2 with the context that is at the top of the stack.

Comment: Almost certainly, but it has allowed us to open a second dialog from WITHIN a first dialog previously (as in the example: we make the `Dialog2` from inside the `Dialog1`: no problems). We'd rather keep the original one open if we can as it makes more sense for the user in this case (the secondary one is a "loading ... " type dialog).  This is why I'm interested in the context and what it does!  Thanks though :)

Comment: I suppose we COULD keep a stack of `Dialog` objects in the Activity and make sure we `getContext()` from the top one ... ?

Comment: You could just pass the context into onSomeOtherCondition to create the Dialog with as well. That's probably easier.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what we're going to have to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem with starting Dialog 2 from Activity 1 when Dialog 1 is visible is because Dialog 1 (not Activity 1) is on the top of the activity stack. I'm by no means an expert, but I suspect that only the Activity at the top of the Activity stack can start new Activities.

Comment: Well, it's a View, not an Activity, but I suspect it is something along the lines you describe, yes.

Comment: Actually to be technically correct a Dialog is neither a `View` or a `Activity`. They are a direct subclass of `java.lang.Object`